# What view to use for such feature?

Tags: android, view, notifications

ALL,

I am trying to port the application from iOS to Android.

In iOS there is a view at the bottom of the screen which holds couple of buttons and it looks like a status bar. One button is implemented as notification button (something like icon in SMS-like applications where you see number in the upper right corner of the icon) and the others are just regular buttons.

This view is always on screen and it looks like a notification area.

Now on Android, how do I implement such a view? Go to each layout.xml and add it there? Can ViewGroup be used for such a view?

Need some guidance here.

Thank you.

[EDIT]

As some people asked here is what I'd like to have.

If you look at the Android phone after boot up (I have an HTC one) there is a grey area at the bottom of the screen. In the middle there is a big button, which says "Phone" and there are 2 smaller buttons - one which directs you to the applications installed and the other is for Personalization of the device.

What we want is something like this with much smaller button images.

[/EDIT]

Comment: example image of such view??

Comment: @tyczj, edit the post with adding explanation.

Answer (score 1):

Tabs on Android are placed at the top of the screen; not at the bottom:
Please carefully read this page: http://developer.android.com/design/patterns/pure-android.html and http://developer.android.com/design/patterns/actionbar.html

[image]

You could of course use a custom View, but developing will be a nightmare.

The contents of tabs can be achieved using ViewPager and Fragments: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.html

While the indicators can be achieved with PagerTabStrips

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/PagerTabStrip.html

Comment: what I'm looking for is to implement area #3. Which link I should read for that? Thank you.

Comment: The actionbar page will explain the "bottom bar", but Android users expect that to relate to selected items.

Comment: I hope you will study the Android design guide before implementing too much.   You should not make an Android app that looks like an iOS app.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what exactly the view is you are talking about without an image but you can create this `layout` in its own xml file then you simply use an `<include>` tag in each xml file. Once you get the properties how you want them it is simply copy/paste into each file, for the most part

I do this in my `layouts`. I extend from a `BaseActivity` or BaseListActivity`and`include`a custom`ActionBar` so I can have the look and functionality I need throughout the whole app.

[Reu-using Layouts](http://developer.android.com/training/improving-layouts/reusing-layouts.html)

Comment: My answer may work for what you want then. You can `extend` your `Activities` from a custom `BaseActivity` and have the functionality for the `Buttons` there then `<include>` the `Layout` in your other `Activities`